# My windows 10 pc keeps shutting down when I press the power button

Tags: windows, windows-10, power

I was wondering if anybody knows why my windows PC shuts down every time I press the power button. And no - I have it set to hibernate when I press the power button.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you sure its not just hibernating?

Comment: Are you sure hibernation is not disabled?

Comment: Yes - hibernation is enabled and set as the power button action - and I had chrome, settings, pycharm and many more apps open. Could it have something to do with having at least 7 of 16 GB ram in use?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following procedure:

1. Goto

   > All Settings -> System -> Power and Sleep
2. Over on the right, find and select the "Additional Power Settings". This will open the old Control Panel in the "Power Options" page.
3. Over on the left, find and select the "Choose what the power buttons do"
4. Change the setting(s) that give you the desired behavior - there are both battery and plugged in settings. Look at the settings for "When I press the power button" and it probably says "Hibernate" or "Shut Down". Change it as you need and try that.

It may require you to sign out/in or restart to really take effect.
Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but It's already set to hibernate on the power button.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate actually includes the shutdown function. The computer saves the RAM to disk, then it literally turns off. It is intended for power saving, especially on laptops. But also works if you want to keep your memory and move the PC.

If you only want it to sleep when you press the power button, you have to set it to do Hybrid Sleep/Suspend, or only Sleep/Suspend. Hybrid sleep is where it saves RAM to disk (as in hibernate) but goes to sleep instead of shutting down, to allow recovery if power is lost, but wake up faster. Normal sleep doesn't save RAM to disk, and just goes to sleep.

In fact, on Windows 8 and newer, it Hibernates by default when you press Shut Down. It is called fast startup. It logs out, then saves the system files to an image on disk to make startup faster.